# MapQuest(Android SDK) : Drop a pin on map and automatically open a window

Tags: android, maps, mapbox, infowindow, mapquest

I'm using MapQuest Android SDK in my application.
I have scenario where I drop a pin on map and I want to automatically open a the window for the pin.

I'm using **MapboxMap.InfoWindowAdapter** and method **getInfoWindow( Marker marker)** . My question here how to automatically open window as soon as i drop the pin.

[image]

I want to open window automatically after dropping the pin?

Here is my code:

```
     @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
    //This is where I pass my poi from poiSearchListview Fragment to my Map Fragment through Activity. So On onResume() if will call this method.
            if (null != getActivity.getPoiFields()) {
                fromSearchFrag = true;
                addPoiMarker(getActivity.getPoiFields());
         }
        }
```

This is my OnCreateView() method:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);

 mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

mPoiFields.clear();
if (null != getActivity.getPoiFields()) {
                    fromSearch = true;
                    addPoiMarker(getActivity.getPoiFields());
}

 mMapboxMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MapboxMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
       @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(@NonNull Marker marker) {

                        View customView = null;
**//Here I have my own window my own images, texts and buttons.**

                        return custom view;
                      }
            });
    }
```

});

This is my method for adding POIMarker on Map at OnResume()

```
        public void addPoiMarker(Fields poiFields) {
            final String name = poiFields.getName();
            poiAddress = poiFields.getAddress() + ", " + poiFields.getCity() + ", " + poiFields.getState();

            Drawable iconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.pointofinterest);
            Icon icon = IconFactory.getInstance(getActivity()).fromDrawable(iconDrawable);
            if (mMapboxMap != null) {

                mMapboxMap.removeAnnotations(); // TO remove all the markers before dropping the Address marker from search.

                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().icon(icon).position(
                        new LatLng(poiFields.getLat(), poiFields.getLng())).title(name);

                mSearchResultMarker = mMapboxMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                mPoiFields.put(mSearchResultMarker, poiFields);



             //  mMapboxMap.selectMarker(mSearchResultMarker);
        // **IF I use selectMarker it shows just the address on the window and
 not my custom window. 
I want to show my custom info window here as selectMarker doesn't clear my issue, what to do ?**.
                }
                zoomToPin(poiFields.getLat(), poiFields.getLng());
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `mapboxMap.selectMarker()` passing in the marker you want to select.

**EDIT:** I modified the demo app example [`CustomInfoWindowActivity`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/annotations/CustomInfoWindowActivity.java) to produce both scenarios you have mentioned in your comment below. I simulate scenario 1 by simply clicking the map (not animating the marker dropping), this calls `mapboxMap.selectMarker()` and displays the custom info window as expected. Scenario 2 is working as expected too when clicking the marker icon.

[image]

if I'm still not understanding the issue, please provide additional code and pictures/videos/gifs of the issue.

Comment: Awesome.. Is there anyway I can open a custom window which I have on my own. Write now by using **mapboxMap.selectMarker()** , I Can open the native window.

Comment: By custom window I assume you mean info window? It should work the same as long as the default info window. If not let me know and I can look further into this.

Comment: Sorry , I keep on pressing enter.
When I drop the pin , and when i tap the pin ..I'm using a custom layout for my window and showing it this way :-
 
`mMapboxMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MapboxMap.InfoWindowAdapter() { @Override public View getInfoWindow( Marker marker) {  **Here I'm inflating my custom View**}`

Same way I want to Inflate my custom window when I drop the pin . By using **mapboxMap.selectMarker()** and adding the marker shows me window(native) with name. Can I show Custom window with I already have like the same way I'm doing it when i tap on the pin?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but you can first make sure to set the infoWindowAdapter and then select the marker. Sounds like you are doing it in the wrong order.

Comment: OK, Let me explain you one more time clearly.
**NOTE** :- I have my own info-window with **ICONS** , **BUTTONS** and **address from POI **. 

I have two scenarios 
1. I drop a pin from poi search >
It should drop a pin and Show my custom info-window.

2. When I'm on Map and i have pin on it. User can tap on it to see the window, and tap anywhere on map it goes away.

I'm able to do the 2nd scenario where in getInfoWindow(Marker marker).
But on the 1st Scenario where I drop the pin and it should show my custom window automatically when it drops.
selectMarker() doesopen a nativewindow

Comment: I've edited my answer testing both scenarios you explain. Like mentioned, if this doesn't solve your issue, please provide code along with any pictures/videos/gifs so I can better troubleshoot your issue

Comment: I have updated my question with code ,Please look at it and Thanks for the demo app. @cammace

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried invoking the [`showInfoWindow()`](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/api/4.2.0-beta.3/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/annotations/Marker.html#showInfoWindow-com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap-com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView-) method on the `Marker`?

Comment: I have two fragments , one is the map view fragment and other is list view with places. When i select item in the list view, pin will be dropped on the map. when I click the pin on map I'm calling ` showInfoWindow() ` . But My problem is to open info window as soon as i drop pin from the onItemClick of the list view?